# What components view does ViewContainerRef refer to if specified as read parameter to `@ViewChildren`

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm reading [this article](https://netbasal.com/exploring-the-various-decorators-in-angular-b208875b207c#.41ju7ujz6) on @ViewChildren decorator and it says the following about `read` parameter:

> ViewContainerRef — You need this token when you need to create
>   templates or components dynamically
>
> ```
> @ViewChildren(AlertComponent, { read: ViewContainerRef }) alerts: QueryList<AlertComponent>
> ```

Is my understanding correct that it returns view containers references of child `AlertComponent` components so I can add content dynamically into these components view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a compiler encounters `{ read: ViewContainerRef }` for any element it creates a view container on this element. Any element can act as a view container. Each component host view can have many child embedded views [which are checked before](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f#0013) the component view child components/host views.

So when you use the following:

```
@ViewChildren(AlertComponent, { read: ViewContainerRef }) alerts;
```

you're basically saying that you want to create a view container on the element which is the host element for the `AlertComponent` component. This view container will house child views of the **current component, not the `AComponent`**. It's not different if you defined a view container on a `div` element. The view container is not related in any way to `AComponent`.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45392684/2545680) for some examples.