# Why the length of the ViewContainerRef is 0 even if it has other components inside

Tags: angular

I have this simple component:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private vc: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this.vc.lenght; // 0
  }
```

And `template`:

```
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
<green></green>
```

So here I clearly have host view created by `green` component inside `ViewContainerRef` of `AppComponent`. Why is `lenght` equal to `0` then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ViewContainerRef` that you inject inside the `AppComponent` constructor is not the container for the `AppComponent` child components/view elements. It actually belongs to the parent component and hence is a container for the parent component child embedded views. Since parent component has no embedded views its length is `0`. But if the parent component had the embedded views you would see other number.

Here is an example. The parent `AppComponent` creates an embedded view and uses `a-comp` element, which is the host element of the `AComponent` as a view container:

```
@Component({
    ...
    template: `
        <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
        <ng-template #t>I am embedded view</ng-template>
        <a-comp></a-comp>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
    @ViewChild(AComponent, {read: ViewContainerRef}) acomp;
    @ViewChild('t', {read: TemplateRef}) t;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.acomp.createEmbeddedView(this.t);
    }
}
```

And now if you inject `ViewContainerRef` into the `AComponent` you will get the `length` of `1`:

```
export class AComponent {
    name = 'A component';

    constructor(private vc: ViewContainerRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.vc.length); // 1
    }
}
```