# add component on click of button in angular 7/8

Tags: angular, components, angular7, angular8, angular-dynamic-components

I have one common component which can be imported when a button is clicked.

In that component there is some common HTML: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-append-prepend-q7rfco)

When I click on the button it throws the following error:

> Error: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined

**app.component.html:**

```html
<div class="row" #appenHere></div>

<div>
    <button (click)="addNewComponent()">Append</button>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, Inject, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NewTileComponent } from './new-tile/new-tile.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('appenHere') target: ViewContainerRef;
  private componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  addNewComponent() {
    let childComponent = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(NewTileComponent);
    this.componentRef = this.target.createComponent(childComponent); // <-- here it's throws an error!
  }  
}
```

**new-tile.component.html:**

```html
<p>This is new</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
...
@ViewChild('appenHere', {static : false, read : ViewContainerRef}) target: ViewContainerRef;
private componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;
...
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-21rhbo)

Comment: still getting error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined. I am using angular 8

Comment: It's not working for dynamic data. IT's not displaying in individual tab. I have 3 tabs. all 3 tabs contains that button, when I click on 1st tab's btn it's adding that component but when I click on 2nd tab's same button, it's adding that component in first tab only, it should add in 2nd tab.

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063676/angular-append-component-to-respective-tabs

Comment: static : true doesn't work with dynamic reference, for another requirement open a new request with the exact title/ explanation.

Answer (score 1):

here is your forked [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-append-prepend-de3dsm?file=app/app.component.ts)

change this line

```
@ViewChild('appenHere',{read : ViewContainerRef}) target: ViewContainerRef;
```

for more reference refer this [StackOverFlow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130243/what-components-view-does-viewcontainerref-refer-to-if-specified-as-read-paramet)

Comment: It's not working for dynamic data. IT's not displaying in individual tab. I have 3 tabs. all 3 tabs contains that button, when I click on 1st tab's btn it's adding that component but when I click on 2nd tab's same button, it's adding that component in first tab only, it should add in 2nd tab.

Comment: Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59063676/angular-append-component-to-respective-tabs