# angular append component to respective tabs

Tags: angular, components, angular7, viewchild, angular-dynamic-components

I am trying to append component (dynamic created) to respective tabs using angular material and `@viewChild` but it is going to first tab only when I click button in the 2nd tab.

**Here is [Stackblitz - angular-append-component-to-respective-tabs](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-append-component-to-respective-tabs-jp5zzt)**

It's not displaying in individual tab. I have 3 tabs. all 3 tabs contains `Add` button, when I click on 1st tab's button, it's adding that component in 1st tab but when I click on 2nd tab's `Add` button, it's adding that component in 1st tab only, it should add in 2nd tab.

Can someone please help me to figure-out how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-append-component-to-respective-tabs-jp5zzt-p7nonq

With ViewChild you always access the first one. Use ViewChildren and access with the selectedIndex

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild`.
`@ViewChildren('appenHere', {read : ViewContainerRef}) tabList: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;`
so you can use it like this:
`this.componentRef = this.tabList.toArray()[1].createComponent(childComponent);`
You can also pass index as parameter to addNewComponent function.

Answer (score 1):

The `target` property of your implementation always points to the div inside the first tab. Which is why the component is always created there.

You can get around this using `ViewChildren` to access the `div`s from all the tabs. And when the user clicks on the Append button, simply pass the tab index to the event handler function and create the component inside the correct tab.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-append-component-to-respective-tabs-jp5zzt-aqwxh7

Answer (score 0):

Loading Three components on Every tab using PrimeNg ang angular Tab component.

**import**

```
import { TabViewModule } from 'primeng/tabview';
import { TabMenuModule } from 'primeng/tabmenu';
```

**html**

```
<tabs id="tabId" #tabsInfo class="tabBorder" style="display: block;">
   <tab id="tab1" tabTitle="Tab1">
       <tab1Componentselector></tab1Componentselector>
   </tab>
   <tab id="tab2" tabTitle="Tab2">
       <tab2Componentselector></tab2Componentselector>
   </tab>
   <tab id="tab3" tabTitle="Tab3">
       <tab3Componentselector></tab3Componentselector>
   </tab>
</tabs>
```

create three components and Add **Add botton** in all component.

Comment: component is dynamic. Please read my question carefully. And I am using `angular material` not `PrimeNG`. Also, tab is dynamic not static.