# Angular: render numerous components on (click)

Tags: javascript, angular

I do not want to render a new component or go to a new route, this is not my intention. I cannot use a single variable with an *ngIf to handle rendering the component as I cannot predict the amount of variables I will need to render.

Here is the situation.

```
<div ngFor="let stuff of lotsOfStuff">
    <div (click)="generateAnotherComponent()">
         <span>some basic info</span>
         <my-child-component></my-child-component> //component to render on click
    </div>
    <div (click)="generateAnotherComponent()">
          <span>some basic info</span>
          <my-child-component></my-child-component> //component to render on click
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot use an array with `*ngFor` and append to it on click?

Comment: I am currently using an ngFor as well. What do you mean by append it on click? Like with vanilla js and the document?

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050989/add-component-on-click-of-button-in-angular-7-8

Comment: That is probably the closest to what I would want, but it still relies on a single ViewChild. Although I think I recall that ViewChild can be used to track an array of references.

Answer (score 0):

You can [generate the component dynamically](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

There are various ways to achieve this, but one would be to use a template variable placed on an element, for example

```html
<div #ChildInsertionPoint></div>
```

And then targeting this "insertion point" as where you'll place the newly generated components by using [`ViewContainerRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef):

```
@ViewChild('ChildInsertionPoint', { read: ViewContainerRef }) 
    childInsertionPoint: ViewContainerRef;

generateAnotherComponent() {
    this.childInsertionPoint.createComponent(ChildComponent);
}
```

Dynamic component generation [became a lot easier with Angular 13](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v13-is-now-available-cce66f7bc296) (that's what I've assumed you're using). But if not
Finally, I'm assuming that you will bind your click event to a button instead of the `div` element itself.

[Here's a small example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-glyecy)